# quickfix window and location list open at the same time causes weird resize

Tags: quickfix, window-management, filetype-go, plugin-ale

I have two different plugins doing different things while writing Go. Sometimes the plugin that runs the testing (vim-go) will write to the quickfix window, while the plugin that does linting (ALE) writes to the location list.

If they happen to be open and modified at the same time, I get a weird resize of the window until it takes up the whole screen.

Anyone seen anything like this before? Is there a way I can set a hard window size that cannot be changed?[image]

Comment: Maybe simply configure your plugins so that they don't trigger at the same time? Linting and testing don't need to be executed at the same time: maybe you can disable the automatic start of tests and keep only the linting or change the events which trigger their execution.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately there is no easy way to fix this at the moment, the OP has opened a [vim-go issue](https://github.com/fatih/vim-go/issues/1571) and we agree that this is something vim-go can do better. Now we just need someone to spend time fixing it :-)

In the meanwhile, you *can* do some things to use ALE and vim-go simultaneously.

1. Setting `g:go_list_type = 'locationlist'` will make vim-go always use the location list. It will *overwrite* the location list, though (so still not perfect), but it's better than having two lists.
   You can also use `g:ale_set_quickfix = 1` to make ALE use the quickfix window, if you prefer.
2. For many things, I use ALE and not vim-go, because I prefer to have the same behaviour in all filetypes:

   ```
   " No gofmt on save. We use ALE.
   let g:go_fmt_autosave = 0

   augroup my_go_settings
       autocmd!

       " Because I use ALE these commands are useless to me.
       autocmd FileType go
                   \  delc GoErrCheck | delc GoLint | delc GoVet
                   \| delc GoFmt | delc GoImports | delc GoFmtAutoSaveToggle
                   \| delc GoMetaLinter
   augroup end

   " Format code for me on :w
   let g:ale_fix_on_save = 1

   " goimports on save.
   let g:ale_fixers = {'go': ['goimports']}

   " Linters
   let g:ale_linters = {'go': ['gometalinter']}
   let g:ale_go_gometalinter_options = '--disable-all'
               \ . ' --enable=vet'
               \ . ' --enable=golint'
               \ . ' --enable=errcheck'
               \ . ' --enable=ineffassign'
               \ . ' --enable=goconst'
               \ . ' --enable=goimports'
               \ . ' --enable=lll --line-length=120'
               " These are slow (>2s)
               " \ . ' --enable=varcheck'
               " \ . ' --enable=interfacer'
               " \ . ' --enable=unconvert'
               " \ . ' --enable=structcheck'
               " \ . ' --enable=megacheck'
   ```

To be fair, vim-go's GoFmt implementation is actually better, and handles more cases. But ALE's syntax checking is better, and the fix_on_save feature works well enough (I use it daily). I plan to spend some time to improve ALE in this regard soon™.

This combination of settings doesn't cover 100% of the cases, but it does most of them, and overall it works quite well for me.

Comment: Thanks for your detailed response, There are no doubt some clashes between `vim go` and `ALE` but I think this specific resize issue was caused by the way that I had the windows set up. Notice how my qf and ll windows were the full width of the screen? It had something to do with the vertical `NERDTree` split and the full horizontal split at the bottom that was actually causing the resize